# Left join part of the table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to join two table using left join, that is `table1 left join table2`.
I would only like part of the rows from A to be joined with B. Is it recommended that i use a sub query to filter rows from table1 or avoid them in where clause to improve my query performance?

```
select t1.a
    ,t1.b
    ,t2.c
from (select * 
      from table1 
      where a='x'
     ) t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.d=t2.d
```

or

```
select t1.a
       ,t1.b
       ,t2.c
from table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.d=t2.d 
where t1.a='x'
```

Comment: They're probably implemented the same. Do you see any difference when you use `EXPLAIN` on the two queries?

Comment: Just use explain - See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html - Will tell you how the statement is being executed

Comment: try to use EXPLAIN to see the difference. But I believe the 2nd one is the best option given that it is straight forward and does not have to do inner query first before the main query.

Comment: I think the second syntax is more common, since it's less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Check the query plan but I doubt it would make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It very depends on the structure and content of your database. The best way is to look into the query plan and compare it for both versions of your query.

You can find this documentation useful: [MySQL Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html)